# How can I create a general method to change the True/False value of different class attributes?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, attributes

I am creating a GUI using a class object for the window. This window has quite a few buttons to turn on and off different panels of settings. A simple example of my class is something like:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class MyWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # flags which are used to draw settings panels if True, and not draw if False
        self.settings1 = True
        self.settings2 = True 

        # create frames for each panel of settings 
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(window, text = "First panel")
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(window, text = "Second panel")
        self.frame1.grid()
        self.frame2.grid() 

        # add button widget to each frame 
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = "ON", bg = "green", command = lambda: self.changeButtonState(self.button1, self.settings1))
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame2, text = "ON", bg = "green", command = lambda: self.changeButtonState(self.button2, self.settings2))
        self.button1.grid()
        self.button2.grid()

    def changeButtonState(self, button, flag):
        if button["text"] == "ON":
            button["text"] = "OFF"
            button["bg"] = "red"
            
            # change the state of the given flag
            flag = False 
        else: 
            button["text"] = "ON"
            button["bg"] = "green"
            
            # change state of flag
            flag = True 

        print("Settings 1: ", self.settings1, "\nSettings 2: ", self.settings2)

# create the window 
window = tk.Tk()
x = MyWindow()
window.mainloop()
```

The button colours and text changes fine, ***but the value of `self.settings1` and `self.settings2` remains unchanged*** when you click the buttons. I do not understand why, since `flag` in the function should be one of the class attributes, but it treats it like a new variable!

How do I create a general function that can alter the state of class attributes that are passed to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference Here is a post explaining why your implementation doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the value of a parameter doesn't change the value used to *set* the parameter. But there's no real reason to pass `self.settings1` to the function; as a method, it already has access to `self`, and therefore *any* setting. First, store the settings in a container, rather than individually named attributes:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.settings = {'setting1': True, 'setting2': True}
    ...
```

Then, pass the *name* of the setting to the call to `self.changeButtonState`:

```
    ...
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = "ON", bg = "green", command = lambda: self.changeButtonState(self.button1, "settings1"))
    ...
```

Finally, use the name to index your `dict` of settings:

```
def changeButtonState(self, button, flag):
    if button["text"] == "ON":
        button["text"] = "OFF"
        button["bg"] = "red"
        
        # change the state of the given flag
        self.settings[flag] = False 
    else: 
        button["text"] = "ON"
        button["bg"] = "green"
        
        # change state of flag
        self.settings[flag] = True 

    print("Settings 1: ", self.settings['setting1'], "\nSettings 2: ", self.settings['setting2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `self.settings1` and `self.settings2` isn't changing is because you are not changing them during the `changeButtonState` function call. Instead, what you do is pass the values to the function. I assume you think the following line:

```
flag = True
```

Should change the `self.settings1` variable. However, this is not the case because of how variables are handled in Python. Here is [an article](https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/) that goes into some detail about the topic.